# $2\times2$ positive semidefinite matrices satisfying $P=P^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$P$ is a $\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$ positive semidefinite matrix satisfying $P=P^2$, $P \neq 0$, and $P \neq I$. Show that
$$P=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos t \\
\sin t
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos t & \sin t
\end{bmatrix}$$
for some $t$.

Comment: Almost verbatim from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4377959/positive-semidefinite-matrix-identity), except you likely missed the "semi" in semi-definite.

Answer (score 1):

As a positive semi-definite matrix, $P$ has positive eigenvalues, and the matrix equation $P=P^2$ implies $\lambda=\lambda^2$ for each eigenvalue $\lambda$. That is $\lambda\in\{0,1\}$. Since $P$ is neither zero nor the identity, we find that one eigenvalue must be $0$, and the other one must be $1$. In particular, $P$ will be the projection onto the span of the eigenvector to eigenvalue $1$. You have free choice of this eigenvector, and after normalization and we can write it as $(\cos t,\sin t)$. You can check that the projection onto this vector is exactly the given matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Since we're talking about positive semi-definite matrices, then it is implicitly assumed that $P$ is symmetric.  So take

$P = \begin{bmatrix} a && b \\ b && c \end{bmatrix} $

From $P = P^2 $ it follows that $ P (P - I) = 0 $ , thus

$ \begin{bmatrix} a && b \\ b && c \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a - 1 && b \\ b && c - 1 \end{bmatrix} $

Hence, we have the following three equations

$ a(a - 1) + b^2 = 0 $

$ a b + b (c -1 )= 0 $

$ b^2 + c (c - 1) = 0 $

**Case I:** $b = 0$, then $ a$ is either $0$ or $1$ and $c$ is either $0 $ or $1$.

**Case II:**$ a + c - 1 = 0 $ then we can take $a = \cos^2 t , c = \sin^2 t $ and it would follow that $ b = \pm \cos t \sin t $

Case I results in two possible matrices (being $\ne 0 $ and $\ne I$ ):

$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 \end{bmatrix} $ and $ \begin{bmatrix} 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

Case II results in $ P = \begin{bmatrix} \cos^2 t && \pm \cos t \sin t \\ \pm \cos t \sin t && \sin^2 t \end{bmatrix} $ which can factored as

$ P = \begin{bmatrix} \cos t_0 \\ \sin t_0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \cos t_0 && \sin t_0 \end{bmatrix} $

where $t_0 = t $ if $b$ is taken with a plus sign, and $t_0 = -t $ if taken with a negative sign.

Also note that Case I is a special case of Case II, by setting $ t= 0 $ or $ t = \dfrac{\pi}{2} $ respectively.